# Android Studio does not run in Elemtary OS

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I am new in Linux (I'm using Elementary OS) and I downloaded Android Studio but, when I trying to open it I get this

```
openjdk 6 is not supported. please use oracle java or newer openjdk.
```

I've read several information about this. I installed a newer openjdk but nothing happens.

I'm counfused because in `/usr/lib/jvm` are a lot of folders` 
[image: folders]

Sorry for the picture but the screencaptures in EOS are black.

What can I do?

Comment: As said in the message - install Oracle Java. I downloaded its linux distro and set up env var when I needed Java on Debian

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have multiple Java environments installed. You might need to switch to openjdk by using the command `update-java-alternatives`.

List all currently installed environments:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
```

Set openjdk:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s your-openjdk-environment
```